# how to adjust the content of my navbar when the screen resolution changes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a navbar with a logo and title of my page, I need the title is in the middle and the logo on the left

but I have a problem, this does not fit when the screen resolution changes, the logo hides the title of my page

My logo must be floating between the navbar and the content of my page

How can I adjust the logo and title to change when changing the screen resolution?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
  <img src="http://www.smartinteriors.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/200x300.gif" class="logo img-fluid" alt="">
  <a class="navbar-brand title-page mx-auto">Title page</a>
</nav>

.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #A1241B;
  height: 100px;
}

.logo {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexcortes53/egrbmcwp/5/)

Comment: Have a look at `@media` queries. You can detect the screen size & apply different css attributes depending on what you're after and the current resolution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .navbar-custom {
      background-color: #A1241B;
      height: 100px;
    }
    
    .logo {
      display: inline;
      position: absolute;
      top: 1em;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .img-fluid {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        width: 150px;
      }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 320px) {
      .img-fluid {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        width: 100px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
    <img src="http://www.smartinteriors.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/200x300.gif" class="logo img-fluid" alt="">
    <a class="navbar-brand title-page mx-auto">Title page</a>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the solution when resizing the screen.

```css
.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #A1241B;
  height: 100px;
}

.logo {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
.logo {
    top: 6em;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0;
    width:100%;
    
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
  <img src="http://www.smartinteriors.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/200x300.gif" class="logo img-fluid" alt="">
  <a class="navbar-brand title-page mx-auto">Title page</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lies in the use of @media Queries. Check this link out [www.w3schools.com/mediaquery.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Using media queries, you can select the screen width and then apply a layout such as flex layouts which will make this process somewhat easier.

For info on flex layouts check this link [css-tricks.com/flex](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/)